# R-Python sieve, 36 times slower than World Record

Tags: python, performance, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes, rpython

I decided to write a sieving prime-finding programme and make it fast. It works correctly but counting the primes below 10**9 takes 36 times as `primesieve` downloaded from http://primesieve.org/.

Now I understand that they have a World Record so they better be fast, but we all know that a compiler is much better than a human at making optimization, so I fear I missed a massive optimization in my implementation.

Some timings:

> ```
> time ./sieve-c 100000000
> Up to 100000000 there are 5761455 primes.
>
> real  0m1.914s
> user  0m1.876s
> sys   0m0.032s
>
>
> time ./primesieve 100000000
> Sieve size = 32 kilobytes
> Threads    = 4
> 100%
> Prime numbers : 5761455
> Time elapsed  : 0.0568619 sec
>
> real  0m0.206s
> user  0m0.192s
> sys   0m0.004s
> ```

---

> ```
> time ./sieve-c 1000000000
> Up to 1000000000 there are 50847534 primes.
>
> real  0m21.408s
> user  0m21.128s
> sys   0m0.252s
>
>
> time ./primesieve 1000000000
> Sieve size = 32 kilobytes
> Threads    = 4
> 100%
> Prime numbers : 50847534
> Time elapsed  : 0.582213 sec
>
> real  0m0.607s
> user  0m2.220s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```

Where should I go next for better performance (wheel factorization, memoization, segmentation, parallelism)?

Also, my code is not able to calculate 10**10 or more because that would take up too much space and my computer crashes. Maybe I should try segmentation?

Please note that R-Python is a subset of Python, so you can run my programme with a regular Python too (but it will be much slower).

```py
import doctest
import math
import sys
import doctest

def sieve(limit):
    """
    Returns the primes below the `limit`

    >>> sieve(9)
    [False, False, True, True, False, True, False, True, False]
    >>> sieve(100000).count(True)
    9592
    """
    sieve = [True]*limit
    sieve[0],sieve[1] = False, False
    sqrt_limit = math.sqrt(limit)
    for number, prime in enumerate(sieve):
        if prime:
            for multiple in xrange(number*2, limit, number):
                sieve[multiple] = False
        if number > sqrt_limit:
            break
    return sieve

doctest.testmod()

def _sum(lst):
    s = 0
    for i in lst:
        s += i
    return s

def main(argv):
    print("Up to " + argv[1] +" there are " +str(_sum(sieve(int(argv[1])+1))) + " primes.")
    return 0

def target(*args):  
    return main, None

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    import sys
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation on primesieve.org? They use several key optimizations to the Sieve of Erastothenes, most notably it's segmented and they use wheel factorization. Your code doesn't do either of those.

Comment: RPython is a really strange target for this IMHO. I'm also not enthused about the "my implementation is slower than another with more optimizations - why?" aspect of the question. I might look at this a bit, but language unfamiliarity will probably prevent any really good answers.

Comment: Please remember to use [tag:python] as well.  That may be a reason why this question hasn't been answered.

Comment: How would Python code be slower in Python than in RPython? R is slower than Python, and I assume any code ran native will be faster. Very curious.